What is the difference between 法制 and 法治?
According to 百度百科, 2020年8月1日，在《法制日报》40岁生日之际，经中央政法委员会、司法部同意，并报国家新闻出版署批准，《法制日报》更名为《法治日报》。
What is the difference between 法制 and 法治?

First of all, in the particular political situation of the mainland China, which is ruled by one party that is further ruled by one person (the de facto King), the concept of LAW is different from that of the western civilization.
In Chinese language, 法制 means 一整套由政府制定和颁布的法律制度，被政府用来约束公民的行动。政府有权力随时发布甚至改变任何法律，政策，规定。The documents of the law system which for the govanment to use to rule the people, and the people have to obey the so called law.
法治 means 政府必须依照法律进行管理并且不得超出法律授权的范围，从而使公民的权利和自由得到保障。The concept of 法治 is promoted by the intelectuals in the recent decades in China.

"Rule by law" v.s. "rule of law", ideally. However, the reality doesn't really changed. It is more or less like using a beautiful wording for propaganda decoration.
In Chinese, it is called “‘刀’制改‘水’治”，change from “制裁”之制 to “治理”之治，with the hidden context of: ruling by brutal force changed to ruling with reasoning and humanity gentle.
For better understood, recommend video from Prof. He Wei Fang (贺卫方教授). Unfortunately, I cannot remember which presentation exactly did he explains this change. Should be somewhere around 2013.

What you say is right. But one fact has been ignored, that is, the law can be altered from tiem to  time, and unfortunately you along with many of your neighbors are the law makers, got it?

I didn't get your point, and sorry, the keyword here is "Rule (as verb)", but not law.

Let me see what point I wanted to make, because after the party of Halloween,It takes some time to get sober again. Yeah, I meant to say,to rule by law is bullshit in China. Lol.

Lol with tears XD

Actually, I think I understand what you mean. Basically, you mean everybody has power or obligate to make a better society. However, "everybody has power" would be a false statement, and the obligation has been filled with full of hypocrisy now days, even globally, like the fascism come back in name of "anti fascism", and racism come back in name of anti racism.

Simple answer: 法制 means: Fabriqué en France, Made in France :)
Longer answer:
法律分析：
Analysis of law:
法制和法治的区别：
The difference between The Legal System and The Rule of Law
1、法制是法律制度的简称，
法制 is the abbreviation of法律制度, The Legal System and (its) Institutions
属于制度的范畴，
(which) belongs to the category of institutions
是一种实际存在的东西；
which is (a kind of) real existing thing.
而法治是法律统治的简称，
but 法治 is the abbreviation of 法律统治, the Rule of Law,
是一种治国原则和方法，
(which) is a principle or method of ruling a country,
是相对于“人治”而言的。
(which) is, so to speak, similar to "The Rule of Man".
2、法制的产生和发展与所有国家直接相联系，
Legal Systems and Institutions  have emerged and developed in all countries and are directly related,
在任何国家都存在法制；等等。
Legal Systems and Institutions exist in any and all countries.
法律依据：
Legal Basis:
《中华人民共和国立法法》第一条 为了规范立法活动，
《The People's Republic of China Legislation Law》Article 1 regulates legislative activity,
健全国家立法制度，
(and) a robust national legislative system
提高立法质量，
(Article 1) enhances legislative quality,
完善中国特色社会主义法律体系，
refines the characteristic Chinese Socialism System of Law,
发挥立法的引领和推动作用，
leads the way in legislative impetus and purpose,
保障和发展社会主义民主，
(Article 1) safeguards and develops Socialist Democracy,
全面推进依法治国，
advances all-round National Rule of Law
建设社会主义法治国家，
to develop the Socialist Rule of Law,
根据宪法，
according to the constitution
制定本法。
thus is Article 1 formulated.
Long answer short:
法制, the abbreviation of 法律制度, refers to The Legal System and (its) Institutions
法治, the abbreviation of 法律统治, the Rule of Law is the guiding principle.

The newspaper was about products made in France? Are you kidding?

"Are you kidding?" What do you think?

Crazy is what I think of you.

法制 - (n) 法令制度 (legal system).

一個法制嚴謹的社會 (A society with a rigorous legal system)

法治 - (v) 以/依法治理 (rule/govern by law), or (n) 法令治理 (law and govern)

一個法治的社會 (A society ruled/governed by law)


如果只是看文字的话(或者说玩文字游戏)，法制 and 法治是不同的汉语词语，但要是结合实际生活中的例子去看法制 and 法治有什么不同的话，我会说法制 and 法治是一个意思，没什么区别，《法制日报》更名为《法治日报》，就是忽悠人的，你以为改了个字，实际生活中真的会有什么变化吗？如果你认为真的会发生变化，我只能说你太年轻了，引用江泽民主席怒斥香港记者的话说就是"too young, too simple, sometimes naive"。你可以 着重 看看一个名叫倪匡的作家的政治观点 见链接 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%80%AA%E5%8C%A1
下面是一张图片：

所以对于 @PdotWang 说的下面的话，我是100%认同的，

First of all, in the particular political situation of the mainland China, which is ruled by one party that is further ruled by one person (the de facto King), the concept of LAW is different from that of the western civilization.

如果你真的想从字面上 (单纯地从文字方面)  理解(or 了解)法制 and 法治，你可以看 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%B3%95%E6%B2%BB 中关于法治与法制，当然有兴趣也可以看看中国大陆法治和法治与人治，请看下面的图片：

说完了字面(或文字)，来说说现实生活中的情况吧。
当你在中国遇到强拆的时候，去找政府部门理论，此时你依靠的是法律武器，但此时政府官员这样回你：
下面是一张图片：

相关的视频可以从 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K05VwYqPaDo 观看
现在的中国完全就是一个人 (the King of China) 说了算，现在这个人的权力比毛泽东远远要大，因为中国已经无人可以制衡他了。
宪法规定中华人民共和国公民有言论、出版、集会、结社、游行、示威的自由。可实际是什么呢？
中国的劳动法规定国家实行劳动者每日工作时间不超过八小时、平均每周工作时间不超过四十四小时的工时制度。实际上中国大部分工厂实现996工作制，好多公司都要求员工加班(也有996工作制)，关于996工作制见 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/996%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E5%88%B6
现在的中国，对于大部分人(明星，检察官，警察，法官，工人，教师，农民等等)维权来说，他们会不约而同地选择在微博 ( https://m.weibo.cn/ ) 上描述自己的遭遇，以期望得到广大网友的关注，成为热点，这样相关部门才会介入调查处理。当这件(不好的，负面的)事情成为热点的时候，和这件事相关的微博往往会被迅速删除掉，有可能造成热度不够，不能够使得相关部门介入调查处理。 (相关部门是哪个部门？这个得问中国的外交部了。)
引用 新东方 创始人 俞敏洪在2013年7月26号说的话就是下面的图片：

在这样的国家讲法律，你感觉能行得通吗？
